# Cross Compiling on OSX to Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, macos, server, raspberry-pi, cross-platform

I am trying to configure an environment on my osx machine that will allow me to cross compile arm6 applications for the Raspberry Pi. I seem to be runnning into a wall when it comes to setting up the toolchain. I am using crosstool-ng and am following multiple guides on setup but my issue comes down to when running the ct-ng build command.

Once I run this command everything seems to be running fine until I get to trying to build the binutils. Once it reaches this depenency it will eventually fail no mater what I do.

This is the ouput that I am seeing:

```
[INFO ]  Installing binutils for host
[EXTRA]    Configuring binutils
[EXTRA]    Building binutils
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:51:72: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_isalnum_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:59:72: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_isalpha_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:75:72: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_iscntrl_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:83:72: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_isdigit_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:91:72: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_isgraph_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:99:72: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_islower_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:107:72: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_isprint_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:115:72: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_ispunct_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:123:72: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_isspace_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:131:72: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_isupper_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:139:73: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_isxdigit_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:147:72: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_tolower_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:155:72: error: use of undeclared identifier 'do_not_use_toupper_with_safe_ctype'
[ERROR]    make[5]: *** [binary.o] Error 1
[ERROR]    make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
[ERROR]    make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
[ERROR]    make[2]: *** [all-gold] Error 2
[ERROR]    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Installing binutils for host'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@216]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_binutils_backend[scripts/build/binutils/binutils.sh@236]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_binutils_for_host[scripts/build/binutils/binutils.sh@101]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@638]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/usr/local/Cellar/crosstool-ng/1.21.0/share/doc/crosstool-ng/ct-ng.1.21.0/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 5:11.00)
[05:12] / make: *** [build] Error 1
```

If anyone has ran into this issue and knows how to fix it. It would be much appreciated. Trying to build from source on the Pi (Model A+ has proven pretty tough as it will eventually crash)

Thank you.

Comment: Probably won't be it, but have you installed the developer tools? If you haven't, type g++ at the command line and a window will pop up prompting you to install them.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this up and running?

Answer (score 0):

Gold linker [cannot be compiled on Clang 6-7](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17473) for now. You should be able to proceed if the linker is disabled via `ct-ng menuconfig` in `Binary Utilities` - `Linkers to enable`.